# Refactoring using State monad

Tags: scala

Here's the pure functional DFS routine which has to drag along `Vector[Boolean]` for constant time lookup. Is there a way to make it more concise and understandable using `State` monad? Sorry for such a concrete question, I've read a bunch of posts about this monad with examples in Haskell and Scala but still don't get it.

```
object Digraph {
  def apply(n: Int) = new Digraph(n, Vector.fill(n)(List.empty[Int]))
}

class Digraph private (val n: Int, val adj: Vector[List[Int]])  {
  def addEdge(u: Int, v: Int) = new Digraph(n, adj.updated(u, v :: adj(u)))

  def postOrder(s: Int) = {
    def _postOrder(s: Int, ordered: List[Int], visited: Vector[Boolean]): (List[Int], Vector[Boolean]) = {
      val newVisited = visited.updated(s, true)
      val toVisit = adj(s).filter(!newVisited(_))
      val init = (ordered, newVisited)
      val reachable = toVisit.foldLeft(init){(acc, v) => _postOrder(v, acc._1, acc._2)}
      (s::reachable._1, reachable._2)
    }

    _postOrder(s, List[Int](), Vector.fill(n)(false))
  }
}
```

Comment: Vector[Boolean] is inefficient, because it will cause boxing of every Boolean value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (I think) an equivalent implementation, using `scalaz.State`:

```
class Digraph private (val n: Int, val adj: Vector[List[Int]])  {

  def addEdge(u: Int, v: Int) = new Digraph(n, adj.updated(u, v :: adj(u)))

  def postOrder(s: Int): (List[Int], Vector[Boolean]) = {
    type S[A] = State[Vector[Boolean], A]

    def _postOrder(s: Int, ordered: List[Int]): S[List[Int]] =
      for {
        visited   <- init[Vector[Boolean]]
        newVisited = visited.updated(s, true)
        toVisit    = adj(s).filterNot(newVisited)
        _         <- put(newVisited)
        reachable <- toVisit.foldLeftM(ordered){(acc, v) => _postOrder(v, acc)}
      }
      yield s::reachable

    val (a, b) = _postOrder(s, List[Int]()).run(Vector.fill(n)(false))}
    (b, a)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, using `State` requires a bit of type boilerplate in Scala, which lacks an easy way to partially apply type constructors. The type alias `S` helps to alleviate this a little. Overall, I'm not sure if I'd choose this implementation over the original, but perhaps it can be improved.